# how to reinit the viewcontroller every time

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am changing the background color from single view controller to all other view controller.
but it is working only when i start with that single controller .
if i started with any other controller  then i am not getting background change for that controller.
I though that because if  i start with some  other controller , its init method is called and    and changes that i am calling from single controller after going to other controller is not appear for other controller.

So how can we reinit the other controller so that changes appear in other controller also.

Comment: In your init method, are you changing color by directly setting the backgroundColor property on the view object?

Comment: i am doing like this where color1 is global that i am taking from single controller to change in this controller
- (void)viewDidUnload {
 // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
 // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
 UIColor *color1=color2;
 
self.view.backgroundColor=color1; 
}

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't re-initialize an object that's already been initialized.

I think you should consider using the viewWillAppear method which is called when a view becomes active.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Check out the Apple documentation
[here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:)